# java change OR to AND

Tags: boolean

I have a if check with OR condition
how to convert to use AND condition

```
if ( a!=null || !a.equals(""))  
  return a
else
  return "n/a"
```

How do I execute this logic using AND && condition ?

Comment: What is this code *supposed* to do? For what values should the original string be returned? For what values should "n/a" be returned? Because of the broken logic the intent is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) to do the login using AND. Simply NOT the entire expression on the inside to get:

```
if (!(a == NULL && "".equals(a)) 
    return a
else 
    return "n/a"
```

Below is the DeMorgan's Law on wikipedia and you can utilize them for AND or OR conversions:

**"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"**

**"not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"**

Comment: but suppose a == null then won't this logic return a instead of returning "n/a"..how will the inner condition be executed? I assume the inner condition is false and you negate it and it becomes true and hence a is returned according to your code

Comment: If a == null and a.equals("") is true, we have if (!(true)) which will become if (false) and thus, return "n/a"

Comment: Be careful doing this. That was my initial answer, but then I realized that if `a` *is* null, then it'll throw an exception on your `a.equals("")`. In order to make use of short circuiting, this won't work. It's right in theory, but probably wouldn't work in practice.

Comment: yes.. but in my case a is just null and not empty so inner condition is false.. thus, (!false) which is true and it returns "n/a"

Comment: @user3838866 Irrelevant. The code will perform the same in both cases (the original and this translation are both logically flawed, but the translation is itself correct). Applying De Morgan's law does not change the semantics in this case.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen You are probably correct. I personally wouldn't write java code like this. Would having "".equals(a) not throw an exception?

Comment: @user2548635, as the user above me said, no. The check for `equals` starts off with testing the value for `null`. So it's a non-issue. That said, I really don't think that's the cleanest way to write code. It's *functional*, but that's only half the battle.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't. The conversion will result in this,

```
!(a == null && a.equals(""))
```

But assuming these two tests weren't just pulled out of thin air as example, if that executes with `a == null` being true, it'll move on and you'll get a null reference exception on the second test.

You have a few logical cases here:

1. a is null -> !(true && NPE)
2. a is "" -> !(false && true)
3. a is "test" -> !(false && false)

The first case is your killer here. It's great in theory, but not in practice.

And even so,  I really don't see why you *want* to do this. It doesn't seem any more clear this way. In fact, I'd switch it around a bit and say

```
if(a == null || a.equals(""))
    return "n/a";
```

I think that's a bit more clear.

Comment: is there a way to check it using && logic instead of switching it around with ||

Comment: @user3838866 why are you so set on using an `&&`? I respect it if you're just going after a better knowledge of logical conversions, but I really think it's much less readable that way at no gain whatsoever.